# Why some of the content is getting cropped off after resizing the page to 7.31 x 11 size?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

When I am trying to resize the page to 7.31 x 11 , some of the content in that page is getting cropped off the window. Below is the link for my output document.

http://www.filedropper.com/mynewdocument

Below is my source code

```
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.InvalidPasswordException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.action.PDActionGoTo;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.documentnavigation.destination.PDPageDestination;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.documentnavigation.outline.PDDocumentOutline;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.documentnavigation.outline.PDOutlineItem;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.documentnavigation.outline.PDOutlineNode;

public class PDFConvert {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidPasswordException, IOException, PrinterException {

        File file = new File("d:\\pdf\\000009.pdf");
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
        PDPage page1 = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);

        PDDocumentOutline outline = document.getDocumentCatalog().getDocumentOutline();
        PDRectangle mediaBox = new PDRectangle(7.31f * 72, 11.0f * 72);
        PDPage reSizepage = printBookmark(document, outline, "");
        if (reSizepage != null) {
            reSizepage.setMediaBox(mediaBox);
        }

        PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
        doc.addPage(page1);
        doc.addPage(reSizepage);

        doc.save("d:\\pdf\\mynewDocument.pdf");
        doc.close();

    }

    public static PDPage printBookmark(PDDocument document, PDOutlineNode bookmark, String indentation)
            throws IOException {
        PDOutlineItem current = bookmark.getFirstChild();

        while (current != null) {
            System.out.println(current.getTitle());

            if (current.getDestination() instanceof PDPageDestination) {

                if (current.getTitle().equals("Table DP-2. Profile of Selected Social Characteristics: 2000")) {

                    PDPageDestination pd = (PDPageDestination) current.getDestination();
                    System.out.println("Destination page: " + (pd.retrievePageNumber()));

                    return pd.getPage();

                }
            }

            printBookmark(document, current, indentation + "    ");
            current = current.getNextSibling();
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course your content is cropped off, that's what you told it to do. You need to shrink the content too, be prepending a scaling matrix to the page content stream:

```
    if (reSizepage != null)
    {
        reSizepage.setMediaBox(mediaBox);

        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, reSizepage, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.PREPEND, false);
        contentStream.transform(Matrix.getScaleInstance(0.9f, 0.9f));
        contentStream.close();
    }
```

similar, but better answer (resets all at the end) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49672166/)

Comment: Be aware, though, that this does **not** move or resize annotations accordingly.